# Remove-SPServiceApplication Hangs

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to run the following Powershell command to remove a service application. The command never returns and just hangs and hangs. Anyone now why?

Remove-SPServiceApplication -Identity -RemoveData

Comment: How do you get around the timer issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you supplied a GUID for your identity switch, right?  If not, you'll need the GUID for that service app.

If so, do you have anything showing up in your SharePoint logs?  This smells of a timer job issue or permission issue to me.

Comment: Yup.  The SharePoint timer job was stopped.  Thanks