# Unable to Remove project service application using powershell

Tags: powershell, project-server

When I run the following command:

```
$spapp = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "Project Server Service"

Remove-SPServiceApplication $spapp -RemoveData
```

I get the following prompt:

> Are you sure you want to perform this action?
>   Performing operation "Remove-SPServiceApplication" on Target
>   "PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Server Service".
>   [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
>   (default is "Y"):

After typing "y" and pressing Enter it stays in a  frozen state, where I cannot get out and also the deletion does not take place.

I have tried to delete the aforementioned service application through the GUI but it times out, thus the reason of using the powershell option.

Any pointers?

Comment: Have a look if the SharePoint timer service was stopped. Possible duplicate http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5482/remove-spserviceapplication-hangs

Comment: the SharePoint timer service was running, however when I open the project service application, I see the following message:  WARNING: Project server provisioning timer job not found.

Comment: Do you have more than one server, so that maybe the timer service has stopped only on one of them?

Comment: 1 server farm..

Answer (score 0):

I would try to couple of things to deleted the Proj service App.

1. Reboot the server and try again.
2. Make Sure SharePoint timer job and Admin job is running.
3. if their is any timer job missing, run the below command to provision all OOTB jobs.

   ```
   $farm = Get-SPFarm

   $farm.TimerService.EnsureDefaultJobs()
   ```
4. I would also check the ULS logs and event Log during that time to get the root cause.